# Confused of the difference between defining a custom priority queue and initializing a heap using methods like make_heap in C++

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I was trying to solve a coding problem which requires me to use heap to get items in particular order. When I was trying to implement the solution using both custom priority_queue and make_heap, I found the ways we pass in our own comparator are different and confusing.

The c++.com says:

```
priority_queue (const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Container& ctnr = Container());
```

Comp is the comparison object to be used to order the heap. This may be a function pointer or function object able to perform a strict weak ordering by comparing its two arguments.

```
void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
              Compare comp );
```

Here comp is a binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

I am confused of the difference of the use to the 2 comp here, and when I try to implement my code:

```
// first I define a functor and a static function, both used to be passed as the comp argument;
class isGreater {
    public:
        isGreater() {}
        inline bool operator() (const ListNode* l1, const ListNode* l2) const {
            return l1->val >= l2->val;
        }
}; 

static bool isLarger(const ListNode* l1, const ListNode* l2) {
    return l1->val >= l2->val;    
}

// then I tried several ways to define a custom pq and heap:

// correct
priority_queue<ListNode*, std::vector<ListNode*>, isGreater> p;

// wrong, error: data member instantiated with function type 
// 'value_compare'(aka 'isGreater ()')
priority_queue<ListNode*, std::vector<ListNode*>, isGreater()> p;

// wrong, passing a function pointer like this is not allowed
// error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
priority_queue<ListNode*, std::vector<ListNode*>, isLarger> p;

// correct
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), isGreater());

// correct, here passing a function pointer like this is allowed
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), isLarger); 

// wrong, the "()" is needed, different from how we define priority queue
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), isGreater);
```

I am confused of the difference of ways we pass comp as argument.Could anyone help me with this puzzles?

Comment: `isGreater` in the last case (calling make_heap) is the name of a class.  Not an instance of a class (functor).  In the first case `isGreater()` constructs an instance.  A functor instance and a function pointer (cases #1 and #2 respectively) are callable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand what is going on, you need to understand the distinction between `isGreater` and `isGreater()`

- `isGreater` is the name of a type. It can go where a type can go, i.e. into template parameters (triangular brackets) and declarations.
- `isGreater()` is a constructor invocation, which produces an *object* of type `isGreater`. It can go wherever an expression can go, e.g. it can be used as a function parameter.

Now the errors should be clear: using type name `isGreater` in place of an object expression `isGreater()` or vice versa is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function in the *template* is a *type*. The comparison function in the constructor or `make_heap` functsion is a callable *object*.

The `isLarger` function is a callable *object* not a type, therefore you can't use it as the template argument for [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

The class `isGreate` on the other hand, *is* a type, that can be used to create a callable object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems all template arguments should be types, and for constructor of make_heap function, its arguments should be callable objects, right? But in the signature of the two expressions, priority_queue (const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Container& ctnr = Container()), and void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp ); the two comps seem to be  the same thing to me. They are both Compare, only difference is passing by value or reference. What's the difference?